# How do I make a method in my Java class return findViewById?

Tags: java, android

I gave my layout file every single element an ID, and in my java class I have a method called locate(). What I'm going to return is:

```
return findViewById(R.id.star);
```

But it says cannot resolve symbol findViewById. Also I don't know what should I declare as return type for the method.
So here's what my code look like.

```
public class Tank {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public String face;

    public Tank(int xPos,int yPos){
        x=xPos;
        y=yPos;
    }

    public RETURNTYPE locate(){
        return findViewById(R.id.star);
    }
}
```

I don't know what should be the return type, and findViewById cannot be resolved. I created this class manually(not auto generated).

Comment: Why do yo want the `Tank` class have a method for returning the star `View`?

Comment: Because I want it to do something to star...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`findViewById`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) is a method of a `View`, as well of an [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)), hence you'll need an instance of `View` or of `Activity` to call it.

Probably it works for you now because you're inside an Activity or a View, but once you move it somewhere else, you'll need to call it on said activity or view, i.e.:

```
View locate(Activity activity) {
  return activity.findViewById(R.id.star);
}

View locate(View view) {
  return view.findViewById(R.id.star);
}
```

Notice I'm returning `View` as the return type? Although this is not incorrect, it's actually not the best and we can make it better.

If you notice, `finViewById` returns a generic type that extends `View`. In other words, a concrete view and therefore we could rewrite the methods above like:

```
<T extends View> T locate(Activity activity) {
  return activity.findViewById(R.id.star);
}

<T extends View> T locate(View view) {
  return view.findViewById(R.id.star);
}
```

Why is this better? Because you won't have to cast it to the right thing. Without generics you would have to call it like:

```
TextView t = (TextView) locate();
```

With generics the code becomes more clean:

```
TextView t = locate();
```

PS: Back some time ago, `findViewById` actually returned `View` and we were all casting the return type. Nowadays, Google changed it for generics and we don't need to.

Comment: What if the activity doesn't have the star? You are recommending a bad practice

Comment: What part of this is bad practice? From the context that was given, I think this answer is enough to understand how to proceed. If the star should always be there within the domain of the app, then I wouldn't add anything else as crashing is for me the right behaviour here since not having the star there would most likely be a developer mistake. If there's the use case that the star doesn't exist, then this has to be handled and I think the OP knows that `findViewById` might return null since I pointed to the docs. PS: I'm not recommending anything, I'm explaining how it works.

Comment: Classes that dont participate in the life cycle should not hold hard references to views or to the context. Just replying the answer is not wrong but is neither the rigth thing to do. Advicing something that is not a good practice to solve a problem is an ethical dilema.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... The class holds no reference. It's a method that receives a parameter and doesn't hold any reference. I agree with what you're saying, but I'm not seeing how it relates to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the scope of the method! Nice talk, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need proper context when using the `findViewById()` like so:

```
public <T extends View> T locate(Activity ctx){
    return ctx.findViewById(R.id.star);
}
```

Comment: What does "T" mean?

Comment: It means, it can return any type that extends the view class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Then what do I add to extend it?

Comment: What if the provided context doesnt have the star view? This advice encourages bad practices

Comment: I agree. On the other hand, beginners won't appreciate the better solution if he/she has not seen the bad ones.

Comment: I changed `Context` to `Activity`.

Comment: Now there's no error! I will try to run it see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

No need to take `Activity` or `Context` for finding the `View`. As every view which you will locate by `findViewById()` will be a child of any `ViewGroup`. So just make it

```
public <T extends View> T locate(View parentView){
    return parentView.findViewById(R.id.star);
}
```